# Joomla issue after upgrade from 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I've just upgraded a Joomla website from 1.5 to 2.5.6 using jupgrade. It's working to some extent, but only showing partial content on each page.

I suspect the problem is that the newer Joomla no longer uses Sections, which the old site did use. Unfortunately I have no idea how to translate that to the new Categories only system.

Could anyone advise as to how it's done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, JUpgrade should deal with content as a whole If it has not worked fully, try running the upgrade again as JUpgrade has been know to be glitchy (providing you have a backup of your old Joomla site) but before doing so, ensure that you're using Joomla 1.5.26 and nothing earlier.

If this fails, you should either contact the developer of JUpgrade or maybe try using a commercial migration tool, such as [SPupgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609).

Hope this helps